# Performance issue in dot net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have a production server (which is available over the internet) in which two applications are running one is in Java and the other is Dot Net. The response of Java application is comparatively faster than Dot Net. For dot net application MVC, My SQL, Entity Framework and LINQ is used. Java application also connected to MY SQL of same server.

In dot net application, the movement it hits the controller action and just before leaving the controller action, it writes the time stamp into log file. There is query executed and filtered the data using LINQ. All these are happening in 2 seconds. But the response to the browser takes time (15-20 seconds). In chrome browser "Network" tab, all the javascripts/css/images are getting loaded in less than 100 ms. I have checked the "Waiting (TTFB)" is taking for the main controller action, it is taking around 15 seconds. Document is also not huge, it is just 20 kb.

Now my question is, 
1. What is the reason for such a huge TTFB ? 
2. How to reduce the TTFB, (did not find proper answer). Is it because of Entity Framework/ LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the controller action?  Also, before returning the results of the LINQ query to the view, call ToList() on the results.  That will actually execute the query; it's possible your query is executing during the view render process.

Comment: I am already doing ToList() before sending to the view. I have included the collection object's count in the log file before leaving the controller. It returns  less than 400 records and the LINQ query result printed in log file within 2 seconds.

Comment: Based on your browser dev tools analysis, this is not a server-side problem. For example, you mention that all the scripts load quickly. The browser can't load the scripts until it has the HTML document, and it can't get that until the server returns its response. At that point, the server is done, unless you have AJAX that's calling back to it. If it's taking a while to render, you either have long running JavaScript that's blocking, bad HTML/CSS that's causing the browser to have to work extra hard to render, you're making AJAX calls that are taking a while, or some combination of the three.

Comment: Just did a small test. I made the View page as empty and just executed the LINQ query. It took 7 - 8 seconds to render the page. With the view it was taking 15-16 seconds, which means though it came out from the controller in 2 seconds (as per the logs) but actually it is NOT. Am I right?

Comment: One more observation, immediately after the IIS restart the memory consumed by w3wp process is 2 GB and keep on increasing and after 20 minutes it becomes 12 GB and remains same even after one hour.

Answer (score 1):

There would be performance issues, for millions of records in Entity Framework/ LINQ if queries are not used properly like using .ToList() function for counting rows instead use .Count() only.

Comment: Use IEnumerable instead of .ToList() if you are using.